# c# Pausing between sendkeys

Tags: c#, .net, automation, sendkeys

I'm doing some automation on a Java-based web page that needs to do some validation between entries, so I thought I'd just do a `Thread.Sleep` between each `SendKeys.Send`, but for some reason it just sleeps for 10 secs (10 x 1sec pauses) as it loads the page and then shoots through the whole form without pausing in between each keypress.

Anyone any ideas why it's doing this, or any suggestions for an alternative way of achieving a pause between sendkeys?

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.Send(strTEST);
```

this is on a `browser_DocumentCompleted` event

Comment: You'd have to show the code for assistance with that. pausing between send keys should be possible.

Comment: No code can run on your UI thread while you put it to sleep.  Not in the browser either.

Answer (score 3):

To pause, you want to use the SendWait function instead of SendKeys: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait(v=VS.90).aspx

SendKeys queues all the keys up and processes them later, as you are seeing.  SendWait processes them and returns.